# How to hide one action item for a particular fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment, android-support-library

I'm trying to hide one action item for a particular fragment, the activity which holds fragment is ActionBarActivity and I already tried below methods.

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true); //method 1
getActivity().getActionBar().hide();//method 2
```

and

```
 inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_logout);
        item.setVisible(false);//method 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [onPrepareOptionMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)) for that:

```
 @Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_logout);
    item.setVisible(false);
}
```

Report that this fragment would like to participate in populating the options menu by receiving a call to onCreateOptionsMenu and related methods.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```